# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ext' referenced before assignment fetchProcess error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to fetch and process data I have created two functions fetch(), fetchProcess()
fetch() is as follows

```
def fetch():
    root= tk.Tk()
    root.withdraw()
    filepath =filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("trace files","*.din"),("out files",".out")))
    file=open(filepath)
    file_path = file.name
    ext= os.path.splitext(file_path)
    print(ext[1])
    readData=file.readlines()
    print("Enter the inputs in following order: cache size only integer(no kb),block size, associativity, cache type=1 for combined and 0 for split,prefetcher buffer size,confidence")
    print("for example: python main.py 32 8 1 0 1 2")
    cacheSize= int(sys.argv[1]) #multiply by 1024 to convert into KB
    cacheSize = cacheSize*1024
    blockSize = int(sys.argv[2]) #For block size
    associativity= int(sys.argv[3]) #for associativity
    cacheType= int(sys.argv[4]) #for cache type 1 for combined and 0 for split
    prefetchBuffer= float(sys.argv[5])
    prefetchBuffer=prefetchBuffer*1024
    confidence= int(sys.argv[6])

    # read line and split data and other intialization
    cacheArray = [[0] * associativity] * int(cacheSize / (blockSize * associativity))  #declaring list for cache array 
    lruArray = [[0] * associativity] * int(cacheSize / (blockSize * associativity))  # declaring list for lru
    instr=[] # declaring list for seperate instruction and data cache
    data=[]
    combined=[] # declaring list for combined cache
    prefetch=[]*int(prefetchBuffer) # declaring list for prefetch buffer
    missData =[]
    return ext,readData,cacheSize,blockSize,associativity,cacheType,prefetchBuffer,confidence,cacheArray,lruArray,instr,data,combined,prefetch,missData
```

fetchProcess code is as follows:

```
def fetchProcess():
    ext,readData,cacheSize,blockSize,associativity,cacheType,prefetchBuffer,confidence,cacheArray,lruArray,instr,data,combined,prefetch,missData=fetch(ext,readData,cacheSize,blockSize,associativity,cacheType,prefetchBuffer,confidence,cacheArray,lruArray,instr,data,combined,prefetch,missData)
    for read in readData:
        split = read.split(' ')
    if ext[1] ==".din":
        label = int(split[0], 10) 
        addr = int(split[1], 16) # convert hexadecimal to decimal
        switch(label)

        return addr
    else:
        addr = int(data[2], 16)
        data.append(addr)
        return addr
        # if count == 4000000:  # limiting the iteration to 4 million as mentioned in the question
        #     # break
```

and finally I am calling one by one function like fetch(); and after that fetchProcess(); but it is giving me error as UnboundLocalError: local variable 'ext' referenced before assignment. I am new to python can anyone help me with my mistake ,Thank you

Comment: fetch();
fetchProcess();

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `fetchProcess` function  you need to call

`ext,readData,cacheSize,blockSize,associativity,cacheType,prefetchBuffer,confidence,cacheArray,lruArray,instr,data,combined,prefetch,missData=fetch()`

not

`ext,readData,cacheSize,blockSize,associativity,cacheType,prefetchBuffer,confidence,cacheArray,lruArray,instr,data,combined,prefetch,missData=fetch(ext,readData,cacheSize,blockSize,associativity,cacheType,prefetchBuffer,confidence,cacheArray,lruArray,instr,data,combined,prefetch,missData)`